# Hide/unhide based on number of values in multifield

Tags: javascript

I want a dependent field to be hidden if a dependee has less than three values, and shown if the dependee has three or greater.

So far in my research, I've not seen a way to do this with states or Conditional Fields, it has "value" but not "number of values."

I would love some help or just to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a matter of a few lines of jQuery script though.

Comment: That's the direction I was headed, but would rather do it with states if possible.

Comment: I believe it isn't possible with states.